# Validate sum of two input fields

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to calculate sum of two fields and validate them. Basically, I need sum of the two input field's value is greater than 100, and want to display a prompt if the sum is less than 100.

So far, I have this:

```
<input type="text" class="input" id="value1">
<input type="text" class="input" id="value2">

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
      var val1 = $("#value1").val();
      var val2 = $("#value2").val();

 });
</script>
```

However, I don't know how to validate the result and display a prompt if the sum of these two inputs is less than 100.

Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Look this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp and this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `focusout` to get the real-time sum and alert the user if sum is less than 100, You can add `keyup` events too, but that won't make sense as it would start alerting as soon as you type. IMO, you should have a button, and on click on that button, the calculation and validation shoud be triggered

And if you already have values populated in the input fields, you just need to call / trigger the `focusout` or `click` event of the button: 
:

```js
$("#value1, #value2").on('focusout', function() {
  var value2 = parseInt($("#value2").val()) > 0 ? parseInt($("#value2").val()) : 0;
  var value1 = parseInt($("#value1").val()) > 0 ? parseInt($("#value1").val()) : 0
  var sumOfValues = value1 + value2;
  if (sumOfValues < 100) {
    console.log('Your sum is ' + sumOfValues + ' which is less than 100');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input" id="value1">
<input type="text" class="input" id="value2">
```

With button:

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
  var value2 = parseInt($("#value2").val()) > 0 ? parseInt($("#value2").val()) : 0;
  var value1 = parseInt($("#value1").val()) > 0 ? parseInt($("#value1").val()) : 0
  var sumOfValues = value1 + value2;
  if (sumOfValues < 100) {
    console.log('Your sum is ' + sumOfValues + ' which is less than 100');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input" id="value1">
<input type="text" class="input" id="value2">
<button>Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks, it works perfectly. However this requires both input fields to be populated with values. Basically, the sum of both fields should be higher than 100, so if the user inputs a bigger value in the first field the second one can be empty as it suits my purpose. ( im at the very beginning with JavaScript )

Comment: Ok, I have removed the mandatory condition. Now even if one is populated, it will work.

Comment: Hey Milan,Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hey Milan,
I am using this code now on the form however I ran into a bit of a problem: when the user types a value lower than 100, the users sees the prompt saying that the value needs to be least 100, however when the prompt is closed the form goes through without the user having the chance to correct the mistake ..any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: Well sure you can stop the form submission. Call the above function on the submission and `return false` if the conditions doesn't meet, else `return true` and form will get submitted.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you but how to i call that function on submission ? as i said at the beginning, i am very new at javascript . just started playing around with it two weeks ago..

Comment: Since I haven't seen your form or other codes, its difficult to explain here.

Answer (score 1):

1. Wrap your inputs in a form
2. Add submit button to get values into variables
3. Write condition logic
4. Add an output html node to output the result

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var val1 = parseInt($("#value1").val());
  var val2 = parseInt($("#value2").val());
  var sum = val1 + val2;
  
  if(sum > 100) {
    alert(sum+ ' is greater than 100')
  } else {
    alert(sum + ' is less than 100') 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input" id="value1" value="70">
<input type="text" class="input" id="value2" value="50">
```

Check this example.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var val1 = $("#value1").val();
 var val2 = $("#value2").val();
 
 var sum  = parseInt(val1) + parseInt (val2);
 
 if(sum > 100) {
  alert('Sum '+sum+ ' is greater than 100')
 } else {
  alert('Sum '+sum+ ' is less than 100') 
 }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" class="input" id="value1">
<input type="text" class="input" id="value2">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="value1">
    <input type="text" class="input" id="value2">
    <button type="sumbit" name="submit" id="submit">check sum</button>
    <p id="resultMessage"></p>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // on button pressed
        $('#submit').on('click', function() {
            var val1 = $("#value1").val();
            var val2 = $("#value2").val();

            // numeric validation
            if (!isNumeric(val1) || !isNumeric(val2)) {
                $('#resultMessage').text('Some field contains not a number');
                return;
            }

            // + operator converts input Strings to Number type
            var sum = +val1 + +val2;

            if (sum > 100) {
                // if sum greather than 100
                $('#resultMessage').text('Sum is greather than 100 (' + sum + ')');
            } else if (sum < 100) {
                // some code if sum less than 100 ...
                $('#resultMessage').text('Sum is less than 100 (' + sum + ')');
            } else {
                // sum is 100
                $('#resultMessage').text('Sum equals 100');
            }
        });

        // function for numeric validation
        function isNumeric(n) {
            return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
        }
    }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may take a function called 'isNumeric' for correct Number type validation. Check this code in jsfiddle if you like: https://jsfiddle.net/Rooksgc/6bgu9z9u/2/