# Validate the sum of three input fields in HTML

Tags: html, validation, input, field

I am trying to to validate the sum of three input fields in HTML to be exactly 100. The Code I found on Stackoverflow for two input fields works only for two fields and not for my modification for three (below is my attempt of the modified code). The original code can be found at [Validate sum of two input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45476203/validate-sum-of-two-input-fields)

I am most grateful for any help or advice! Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>       src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="value1">
    <input type="text" class="input" id="value2">
    <input type="text" class="input" id="value3">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">check sum</button>
    <p id="resultMessage"></p>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // on button pressed
        $('#submit').on('click', function() {
            var val1 = $("#value1").val();
            var val2 = $("#value2").val();
            var val3 = $("#value3").val();

            // numeric validation
            if (!isNumeric(val1) || !isNumeric(val2) || !isNumeric(val3)) {
                $('#resultMessage').text('Some field does not contain a number');
                return;
            }

            // + operator converts input Strings to Number type
            var sum = +val1 + +val2 + +val3;

            if (sum > 100) {
                // if sum greather than 100
                $('#resultMessage').text('Sum is greather than 100 (' + sum + ')');
            } else if (sum < 100) {
                // some code if sum less than 100 ...
                $('#resultMessage').text('Sum is less than 100 (' + sum + ')');
            } else {
                // sum is 100
                $('#resultMessage').text('Sum equals 100');
            }
        });

        // function for numeric validation
        function isNumeric(n) {
            return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
        }
    }); 
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My problem is that the modification does not work and I don't see why..

EDIT Per the comments, I have removed the extra parenthesis around !isNumeric(val2).
The problem still persists though. I see the three text boxes and a check sum button. However, whenever I enter any numbers and hit "check sum", nothing happens, no computation of any sum and no display of any sum.

I would be very grateful for any additional comments.

Comment: Are you getting any of the text to appear? Also can we see the HTML?

Comment: Thank you Jake! When I run the code, I only see three textboxes for numeric entry and I check sum button. When I enter numbers in the boxes and hit check sum nothing happens.

Comment: Check the browser console; you have an extra close parenthesis here: `if (!isNumeric(val1) || !isNumeric(val2)) || !isNumeric(val3))`. (after the val2)

Comment: Thank you @DanielBeck, I've changed the sum line but nothing shows.

Comment: Sorry, my first comment was incorrect; you're using an unusual way to coerce the input values into numbers instead of strings, which I didn't recognize (and I glossed right past the comment explaining it! Oops :)   (Typically I use `Number()` which is more explicit than the extra `+`).  That part is ok, the extra parenthesis is the actual bug.

Comment: Thank you @DanielBeck! I've removed the extra parenthesis!

Comment: @DanielBeck Previously I had <input type="number" step = 1 min="0" max="100" name="value1" size=3 required="requires input" /></p> but changed it to what I have in the code above for simplicity. Do you think I should change it back to simplify the code? Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately `<input type="number">` doesn't do what you'd expect; it will only allow number-like input, but still contains a string that needs to be converted into a number in javascript.